# Configure Remote App using guacamole

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, ubuntu-18.04, guacamole

I had set up guacd and default guacamole client using docker in my ubuntu system. I am able to achieve remote desktop connection to another Windows 10 system using RDP protocol. But I want to configure a RemoteApp in remote system. I have configured remote app(named as calculator) for calculator app in remote system using "remoteapp tool kim knight" in D:\temp folder. But I am not able mention the correct path details for the remote app in guacamole client. Ex: [image].